# Prove that there exists $P(x)|P(x^2-2021)$

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

**Problem:** $\exists P(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x],$ $\deg P=2022$, such that,
\begin{align}
P(x)|P(x^2-2021)
\end{align}

**Attemps**

So what I have known is that any polynomial with real coefficients can be reduced into polynomials of degree 2 (which then becomes irreducible) or of degree 1.

But as 2022 is even, I try to factorize $P$ into $1011$ polynomials of degree 2, and prove that for all $P_n$, then $P_n(x) | P_n(x^2 -2021)$

After that I got stuck because it turns out that I couldn't find more than 4 solutions.

Is my direction correct, and is there any other way around?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You need that if $x_0$ is a root of $P,$ then $x_0^2-2021$ is a root of $P.$

Comment: But then $x_0$ is complex right?, because $P$ does not necessarily have real roots!

Comment: Well, there are simple examples with real roots, but in general, for problems like this, you could get complex roots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x_0$ is a root of $P(x),$ you need $x_0^2-2021$ to be a root of $P(x).$

The easiest way to do this is to solve:  $$x_0^2-2021=x_0.\tag1$$
You get this has real roots, $$\frac{1\pm\sqrt{8085}}2.$$

Then take $P(x)=(x-x_0)^{2022}.$ Then since $x_0$ is a root of $x^2-x_0-2021,$ $x^2-x_0-2021$ is divisible by $x-x_0,$ and thus $P(x^2-2021)$ is divisible by $P(x).$

Of course, $(1)$ has two roots, and if $x_1$ is the other root, you can get lots of polynomials:

$$P_m(x)=(x-x_0)^m(x-x_1)^{2022-m}$$

If $m=1011,$ you get:

$$P(x)=(x^2-x-2021)^{1011}$$ And thus you have an example which is an integer polynomial, and this would work even if the roots of $(1)$ were complex.

These aren’t the only possibilities. Roots of $(x^2-2021)^2-x-2021$ can also work, but they must come in pairs. This polynomial has the original two roots, and additional roots $(-1\pm\sqrt{8081})/2.$ But these roots have to occur in pairs. So you could also us: $$P(x)=(x^2+x-2020)^{1011}$$

---

If $Q(x)$ is a real polynomial of degree $d,$ and there are $d$ distinct roots to $Q(x)=x,$ then $P(x)=Q(x)-x$ is a polynomial such that $P(x)\mid P(Q(x)).$

(Not sure we need the “distinct” condition, but just being cautious.)

We can take any powers of this.

---

If $Q(x)=x^2-2021,$ we can also solve $Q^{\circ3}(x)=Q(Q(Q(x)))=x,$ ignoring the roots of $Q(x)=x.$ So:

$$P_3(x)=\frac{Q^{\circ3}(x)-x}{Q(x)-x}$$ is an integer polynomial of degree $6$ which works, and we can take $$(P_3(x))^{337}$$

This is our third distinct integer polynomial.

There are lots more:

$$(x^2-x-2021)^i(x^2+x-2020)^jP_3(x)^k$$ where $i+j+3k=1011.$